# Exception catching in FORM-ENDFORM in subroutine

Tags: forms, exception, try-catch, abap, subroutine

I am using a subroutine (`FORM`, `ENDFORM`) where there is a class-method calling that raises an exception. I am catching the exception from the class-method calling, but how can I pass this exception to where I call the subroutine (`PERFORM`)?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't see how a code example is necessary in this particular case. The question seems clear enough without one to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a documentation section for [Class-Based Exceptions in Procedures](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abenexceptions_procedures.htm) .

> If a class-based exception is not handled in a procedure, the system attempts to propagate it to the caller of the procedure. The exceptions that can be propagated from a procedure must be declared in its interface. The caller then knows which exceptions to expect from the procedure. Class-based exceptions are divided into three categories, which determine whether the declaration must be explicit and how it is checked.
>
> In methods of local classes and subroutines, the addition RAISING of the statements METHODS and FORM is used for the declaration
>
> Undeclared exceptions cannot leave a procedure and violate the interface if they are not handled within the procedure. A violation of the interface raises an exception of the predefined class CX_SY_NO_HANDLER, whose exception object contains a reference to the original exception in the attribute PREVIOUS.

See also documentation for [FORM RAISING](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abenexceptions_procedures.htm).

```
START-OF-SELECTION.
TRY.
  PERFORM test.
CATCH lcx_some_exception INTO DATA(lx_ex).
ENDTRY.


FORM test RAISING lcx_some_exception.
  DATA(lo_test) = NEW lcl_test( ).
  lo_test->test( ).
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: hello @peterulb , this one exactly worked. Thanks a lot.